# Telerik NotSupportedException Grid using helper class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, telerik

So I am trying to clean up some of my code because I dont want to add 30 extra lines of code for something I will be repeating often. But I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

I am using Entity Framework to get the records from my database and then trying to pass that IQueryable to a helper method to do the work and pass an IQueryable back to the initial variable. Then after that the method finishes with converting to a DataSourceResult for Telerik's Grid. The reason i think it is the helper method that is causing the issue is because I can put this all in the controller method and it works perfectly fine. But when I try to split it out, then it stops working and throws errors. So i must be doing something wrong.

Helper Method:

```
public static IQueryable<DetailedTicketModel> GetDetailedTicketModels(IQueryable<TICKET> tickets)
{
    using (var ctx = new GuardianContext())
    {
        var detailedTickets = tickets.Select(v => new DetailedTicketModel()
        {
            Id = v.ID,
            RequesterId = v.REQUESTER_ID,
            RequesterName = v.REQUESTER_NAME,
            Phone = v.PHONE,
            Location = v.LOCATION,
            Source = v.SOURCE,
            PersonAssigned = v.PERSON_ASSIGNED,
            Created = v.CREATED,
            Updated = v.UPDATED,
            DeptId = v.DEPT_ID,
            DeptName = ctx.DEPARTMENTS.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == v.DEPT_ID).NAME,
            TopicId = v.TOPIC_ID,
            TopicName = ctx.TICKET_TOPICS.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == v.TOPIC_ID).NAME,
            StatusId = v.STATUS_ID,
            StatusName = ctx.TICKET_STATUSES.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == v.STATUS_ID).NAME,
            PriorityId = v.PRIORITY_ID,
            PriorityName = ctx.TICKET_PRIORITIES.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == v.PRIORITY_ID).NAME,
            PriorityHexColor = ctx.TICKET_PRIORITIES.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ID == v.PRIORITY_ID).HEX_COLOR,
            TicketEvents = ctx.TICKET_EVENTS.Where(t => t.TICKET_ID == v.ID).OrderBy(t => t.CREATED),
            RequestBody =
                ctx.TICKET_EVENTS.OrderBy(t => t.CREATED).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TICKET_ID == v.ID).BODY,
            RequestFormat =
                ctx.TICKET_EVENTS.OrderBy(t => t.CREATED).FirstOrDefault(t => t.TICKET_ID == v.ID).FORMAT,
        });
        return detailedTickets;
    }
}
```

Controller that calls to the method:

```
public ActionResult UnassignedTickets_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("UnassignedTickets_Read");
    using (var ctx = new GuardianContext())
    {
        var detailedTickets =
            TicketHelper.GetDetailedTicketModels(ctx.TICKETS.Where(v => v.PERSON_ASSIGNED == null));
        //PROBLEM HAPPENS AT THE NEXT STATEMENT
        var result = detailedTickets.ToDataSourceResult(request, ticket => new
        {
            ticket.Id,
            ticket.RequesterId,
            ticket.RequesterName,
            ticket.Created,
            ticket.RequestBody,
            ticket.RequestFormat
        });
        return Json(result);
    }
}
```

Here is the output when the error occurs

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

And if it helps here is the razor code

```
@if (ViewBag.UnassignedTicketsAvailable)
{
    <h3 class="page-header">Unassigned Tickets</h3>

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Guardian.ViewModels.DetailedTicketModel>()
      .Name("unassigned_grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(ticket => ticket.Id).Visible(false);
          columns.Bound(ticket => ticket.RequesterId);
          columns.Bound(ticket => ticket.RequesterName);
          columns.Bound(ticket => ticket.Created);
      })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("UnassignedTickets_Read", "Ticket"))
      )
      .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .Filterable()
    )
}

<script id="client-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Raw("<div style\"padding: 0.4em;\">#=RequestBody#</div>"))

</script>

<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I needed to do eager loading in my helper class. So where my return is I should have had...

```
return detailedTickets.ToList();
```

Hope this helps someone.